# AWS APIGateWay invoke Lambda Error with file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to make a text extractor program using AWS Rekognition. So user should make a get request using the API with an image, and in return he gets the texts of that image.

Therefore I've made a rest-api with ApiGateway and connected it with a lambda function. The Get request works fine when I do not include any files. But the moment I add files to the body or form data, it shows this error (even after adding binary media types on API settings):

[image]

I know we can upload image to S3, then a notification can invoke lambda. I've made that too. It works but I don't want that. The main purpose is I don't want to save user images. I just want to process image file using Rekognition and return the text in the simplest way possible.

Can we not do this with ApiGateway and Lambda? If not, why? If I have to store the image in S3 then process, and then try to remove the file using another event trigger - wouldn't that be overkill?

Comment: I don't know whether this can be done with ApiGateway and Lambda and no intermediate S3. Can you pinpoint the documentation that gave rise to the belief that it could work in this way? Perhaps that should be the first port of call - maybe AWS just doesn't support this arrangement.

Comment: Actually I haven't seen any posts that says we can pass file to lambda using APIGW, neither found any posts that says we can't.

Comment: OK, are there any docs for Rekognition that give a simple architecture diagram? I'd say that in the absence of anything at all to support your theory, you may be better off building it in a way that you know will work. But perhaps a reader can give you a steer.

Comment: The doc I used to complete my POC is this one [from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/text-detecting-text-procedure.html). It used s3 file object.

But the main concern is not about Rekognition. The lambda has to get the file first, then we can see if Recognition allows that or not.